# Change photos on variation - Woocommerce Single Product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, swiper.js

I would like it to change the image on this custom loop when I change the product variation.

When click on variation that has image, change the $image_src_url to chosen variation.

product-image.php :

```
<?php
global $product;

$attachment_ids  = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();
$image_urls      = array();
$image_id        = $product->get_image_id();
if ( $image_id ) {
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_id, 'full' );

    $image_urls[ 0 ] = $image_url;
}

foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
    $image_urls[] = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
}
?>
<div class="swiper swiper-single-product">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <?php 
        foreach ( $image_urls as $image_src_url ) {
            echo '<div class="swiper-slide"><figure class="zoom"><img src="' . $image_src_url . '"></figure></div>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-single-product", {
slidesPerView: 1,
grabCursor: false,
preloadImages: false,
lazyLoading: true,
pagination: {
  el: ".swiper-pagination",
  clickable: true
}
}); // zoom image
```

Comment: Please make more clear what you are trying to do and what is not working.  I see that you are giving all the elements an id of 'ex1'. This could be a problem, ids are meant to be unique.

Comment: I would like it to change the image when I change the product variation.
I already remove the id="ex1".

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the swiper class to your JS.

```
var swiper = new Swiper("swiper.swiper-single-product", {
slidesPerView: 1,
grabCursor: false,
preloadImages: false,
lazyLoading: true,
pagination: {
  el: ".swiper-pagination",
  clickable: true
}
}); // zoom image
```